# Python RotatingFileHandler without renaming existing files

Tags: python, logging, log-rotation

In python, the RotatingFileHandler  keeps on changing file extensions every time a rotation takes place.

I would really like filenames / filename extensions to be fixed instead - after creation then never change.

Example of how it would work:

Time 0:

- Log file is created with application_name.20210301_130601
- Application logs to application_name.20210301_130601

Time 1:

- application_name.20210301_130601 reaches 5MB in size
- Existing application_name.20210301_130601 log is closed.
- New log file is created with application_name.20210301_140803
- Application logs to application_name.20210301_140803
  NOTE: NO RENAMING OF EXISTING LOGS HAS TAKEN PLACE

Time 2:

- Same as time 1

Time 3-9:

- Same as time 1

Time 10:

- Total size of logs is 50MB
- First log application_name.20210301_130601 is deleted

How can I achieve this? Is the only way to override doRollover ?